# AJAX GET return error >The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'

Tags: jquery, .net, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I saw lot of post regarding this, but i don't seem to find the answer,
I am trying to call controller Get method though AJAX

### JS

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
 $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "api/CookBooks/",
                dataType: "xml",
                success: function (data) {
                    $.each(data, function (key, val) {
                        debugger;
                    });
                },
                error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    debugger;
                }
            });
        });
```

### Controller

```
[HttpGet]
public static IEnumerable<DTO> GetLatest()
{
// ...
}
```

i am getting response error "he requested resource does not support http method 'GET'"
Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have other HttpGet method inside controller?

Answer (score 0):

you can call your controller Get method like below

```
$.ajax({
        url: "controllerName/MethodName",
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json', // added data type
        success: function(data) {
            $.each(data, function (key, val) {
                    debugger;
                });
        }
    });
```

Make sure you have proper names of controller method and that names you used in this ajax call,

along with that, if you have apis then only you have to add api as prefix, but if your project is mvc type then no need of appending api prefix

Comment: after that change (dataType) > same error appear, also tried the suggestions of the api prefix and the method name explicitly

Comment: Check the static Method? Do you really want to create your GET method as static

Comment: I believe if you mark your method with static then you have to create access that method with class name. but controller is initiating once per request due to that reason I don't believe static is needed here, but please check that